# PHP can not connect to SQL Server database even with the drivers installed correctly

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

My notebook had a screen problem, so I took another one borrowed for some days to continue to develop my projects.

I installed XAMPP, SQL Server 2012 Express and SQLSRV extentions, but I could not connect to the database.

My phpinfo() shows that the sqlsrv is installed:

[image: sqlsrv working]

This is the string connection that I'm trying

```
<?php
//phpinfo(); die();
try{
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=JRMNOTE1\KEOMA;Database=BudgetOne", "sa", "password");
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(Exception $e){ 
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) ); 
}
```

And this is the output:

```
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=1637121
```

I tried to install the ODBC drivers from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36434), but this didn't work too. I really don't know what I could try next and did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday night I definitely gave up. I formatted the hard disk and reinstall the Windows. After reinstall XAMPP, SQL Server (then I tried the 2014 version) and the PHP drivers, the connection worked.